# visual studio mac ios bundle signing platform is always iphone simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, device

I am having troubles using my iPad as a testing device for my Xamarin.Forms App Running in Visual-Studio-2017. I have already done the requirements to use my own app but it still doesn't show on the devices. Here are the steps I have done so far.

1. Created my own account on free provisioning as described on this site. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos
2. Opened my Xcode and created an empty app to setup the free provisioned account as described on the link above.
3. Fixed my the codedesign keychain access by inputting my Mac password and clicking always allow
4. Changed my `info.plist` information on signing as shown below
   [image]
5. On bundle options, I have changed my signing identity and provisioning profile created by xcode. and changed the platform to iphone and clicked ok. See the image below. 
   [image]
6. After I clicked ok, Visual Studio says it was saved. But everytime I checked on my a debug device, it only shows simulators! Shown below:
   [image]
7. I have tried restarting visual-studio mac numerous times but still how the same result! My devices hasn't shown at all!

I have scoured the internet and I couldn't find any concrete solution.

Comment: In the Apple Developer Account, did you add your iPad to the list of development devices for your profile?

Comment: I didn't go to the Apple Developer Account, I just used the free provisioning that I just needed to do on the Xcode.

Comment: I was going to suggest looking for your device in Xcode, but you've found your solution already! :)

Comment: Yes, it was apparently fairly easy to miss! But thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution. Just change the Debug to Debug | iPhone as shown below... And it will show your device.

[image]